# Razor html encode not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
@using MvcMusicStore.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Album>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "List2";
string hola = "Test <script>alert('bip')</script>";

}

 <h2>@@List2</h2>
 <span>@hola</span>

 <ul>
  @foreach (Album a in Model )
   {
<li>@a.Title,@a.Tipo</li>

}

</ul>
```

I've read that razor automatically html encode strings, but with the code above on my view
i still get the string as is without any encoding.

Btw im running on the localhost just in case it affects in any way.

Thanks in advance

Update:

Thanks to all of your answer specially to Codo answer. The problem was that i was just
looking at the text printed on the page, but not to the page source where the encoded is
reflected.

Thanks

Comment: When you say that you "get the string as is", What do you mean exactly? Does the message box with "bip" in it show up or not?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I mean that it prints: Test <script>alert('bip')</script> without applying any encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reduced the test case to the relevant part:

```
@{
  string hola = "Test <script>alert('bip')</script>";
}

<span>@hola</span>
```

When executed, it produces the following HTML code (when looking at the source HTML):

```
<span>Test &lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;bip&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;</span>
```

In the browser, it displays:

> Test <script>alert('bip')</script>

And it does not execute it as Javascript code and does not display an alert box.

So I'd say it works as advertized and properly encodes the HTML.

Comment: Great!! it cleared up my confusion, thanks

Comment: @lcaminero you should consider accepting Codo's answer as it clearly helped you solving your problem.

Comment: @Bardo Just did, it was my first post here and didnt knew how to accept it. I was trying to vote it up instead of accepting it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the problem here:

```
<span>@Html.Raw(hola)</span>
<br />
<span>@hola</span>
```

Result as Visible in the browser:

```
Test 
Test <script>alert('bip')</script>
```

AND the is the "alert pop up" saying bip.

Note: it this isn't the answer you are looking forward then please explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: The OP's problem is that it isn't encoded when he expects it to be, not that he's trying to get the raw output.

Comment: @DocMax exactly i want it to be encoded, but i dont know why it isnt encoding it, the answer provided is for not getting it encoded, whereas i want it to be encoded